# Text within component won't align vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a banner component inside of a `div` using CSS grid and I can't figure out how to vertically center the text. Right now, I can horizontally center it but it is align to the top of the div. I know CSS grid makes `vertical-align` not work so I tried `align-self`, `place-self` and `justify-self` but none of those worked either. All of the other threads seem to suggest those were solutions. Here is the code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Banner.css';

const Banner = () => {
    return (
        <div className="banner-cont">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Banner;
```

```css
.banner-cont {
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;

    background-color: #0193fd;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.banner-cont h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    place-self: center;
}
```

And the result: [image]

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: you need to add display: grid on your .banner-cont, and align-content: center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using properties of `flexbox` and `grid` without declaring them first. To use properties such as `grid-column`, `justify-content`, etc... You first need to declare the `display` property, whether it's `flex` or `grid`. I've added a snippet below for your reference. Read more on `flexbox` and `grid` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) respectively.

Using `grid` to align `h1` to the center of the container:

```css
.banner-cont {
  display: grid;
  background: #0193FD;
  place-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.banner-cont h1{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-cont">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Using `flexbox` to align `h1` horizontally:

```css
.banner-cont {
  display: flex;
  background: #0193FD;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.banner-cont h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-cont">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: grid;` to `.banner-cont`

```
.banner-cont {
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    display: grid;
    background-color: #0193fd;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout*

*Result:*

[image]